# How the regular expression getting expanded?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have  the below piece of shell script and output as below. How the regular expression is getting expanded and actual files are being printed in the current directory?

*SCRIPT*

```
echo "1: $dest_file_pattern"
dest_file_pattern=$(echo $dest_file_pattern | sed -e 's/\r//g')
echo "2: $dest_file_pattern"
```

*OUTPUT*

```
1: employee_p000_fr_*.*.pgp
2: employee_p000_fr_20191109141001734.txt.pgp employee_p000_fr_20191110141057316.txt.pgp
```

My requirement is to keep the regular expression and remove the carriage return.

Comment: First, there are no regular expressions here; `dest_file_pattern` (initially) contains a glob, which the shell expands using pathname expansion when you have the unquoted expansion of `dest_file_pattern`. After that, `sed` is simply reading a sequence of file names, and probably doing nothing, because it's unlikely there are any carriage returns in the file names. (It's *possible*, but I feel like your intent is to strip a trailing carriage return that you think the expansion will add. `bash` wouldn't add any carriage returns to the resulting file names, though.)

Comment: What do you want to achieve with `sed -e 's/\r//g'`? Does `$dest_file_pattern` contain a `\r`?

Comment: Are you trying to remove carriage returns from multiple files?

Comment: learn to debug your scripts by setting `set -x` to see what values are being used for each variable. In general, you want to dbl-quote all references to variable names like `echo "$dest_file_pattern" | ...` Copy/paste your code one line at a time to a terminal command line so you understand what is happening in each step. For cases like `var=$(some_cmds ...)`, execute separately `some_cmds`, starting from the left and adding `| next_cmd` one step at a time. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `echo $dest_file_pattern` your shell will expand the file name patterns before executing `echo`.

Use

```
dest_file_pattern=$(echo "$dest_file_pattern" | sed -e 's/\r//g')
```